# How can I copy folders using sftp?

Tags: sftp

I wanted to know if there is an option in `sftp` by which I could copy a folder from a remote machine to local machine.

thanks

Comment: You mean, like using a SFTP client?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Linux you should be able to copy files directly using following command.

```
scp -r <remote-ip>:<remote-directory> <local-target-directory>
```

Or you can mount the SFTP directory on local machine:

```
sshfs <remote-ip>:<remote-directory> <mount-directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `lftp`.

```
lftp sftp://...
```

Then use the `mirror` command. Read the manual for more help, `lftp` is well-documented and awesome.

Answer (score 4):

get -r folder_name in place of get folder_name usually works

Answer (score 0):

Try JCraft and open "sftp" channel using the those API's.